# select distinct records from two tables that has data in multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
Topic
----------------------
id  title
----------------------
1   Loops
2   Control Structure
3   Basics

Chapters
------------------------------------------------------
id  book_id topic_id chapter_number
------------------------------------------------------
1   1       1       1
2   1       2       2
3   1       3       3
4   2       1       5
5   2       3       2
6   3       3       1
```

When searched for topics, I want to show book_ids that has chapters on those topics.
Book_ids that have topic 1 and 2: **1**
Book_Ids that have  topic 3: **1,2,3**
BookIds that have topic 1 and 3: **1**

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT chapter.book_id FROM chapter Inner Join topic ON topic.id = chapter.topic_id WHERE topic.id IN  ( '1,3');
```

but it return Book_ids of : 1 and 3 while it should only return 1. It seems my query returns union while it should return an intersection.

Can someone help me fixing it?

Comment: it returns 1 and 2, you need for topic 1 and 3  return just  1 ?

Comment: WHERE topic.id IN  ( '1,3') means "1 or 3", not "1 and 3", which is what you seem to need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3835/18). Just replace `'1,3'` in this query to any set of chapters you need:

```
select book_id from Chapters
where FIND_IN_SET(topic_id,'1,3')
group by book_id 
having 
count(*) =
(length('1,3')-length(replace('1,3',',',''))+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In "IN" you should put comma separated values. With your query you expect to see sub-set which contains '1, 3' string value not 1 or 2 or 3 int values. Correct query is below

```
SELECT DISTINCT chapter.book_id 
FROM chapter 
Inner Join topic ON topic.id = chapter.topic_id 
WHERE topic.id IN  (1,3);
```

or if you want only IDs

```
SELECT DISTINCT book_id 
FROM Chapters 
WHERE topic_id IN (1,3);
```